# looking for a way to Import an xlsx sheet into google sheets using python - not an API that I have to set up on every machine

Tags: python, google-sheets

long story as short as I can make it
I need a way to automate using the google sheets online File/Import function

I've built a script that takes some mostly worthless data and organizes it into something useful
we have been using Miscrosoft OneDrive or Sharepoint, but you have to ask everybody to get out of the sheet to push a new version up to the web

we found that using the google drive, once you have a sheet online, you can just go online to the sheet, hit File--->Import, and then just select it from the google drive or upload any file you want, which means teh update is real time to anybody who is still online looking at the sheet, or if somebody forgets to log out at the end of the day(which is usually the case we run into)

is there a way to do this where I wont have have each user of a different sheet install or setup the API requirements?
thats actually the biggest roadblock right now....
is just its not a simple thing to set up, and we dont have a global storage location at this time, and multiple offices will be using the script to format their own daily data

***Example Data***

---

```
*Original File - User adds their Own Notes*

Product       Order              Notes
Item A       Order#12345        Items shows up Thursday via FedEx
Item B       Order#12345
Item C       Order#33333
Item D       Order#66554        Ship via Customer UPS Account
```

```
*New Report pulled from Software*

Product       Order              Notes

Item C       Order#33333
Item D       Order#66554
Item E       Order#77777
Item F       Order#93939
```

```
*Final desired Product after Merging User Notes Old Version with the New File*

Product       Order              Notes

Item C       Order#33333
Item D       Order#66554         Ship via Customer UPS Account
Item E       Order#77777
Item F       Order#93939
```

Comment: Can I ask you about your situation? 1. You want to make users import a XLSX file in user's local PC to the existing Spreadsheet on user's Google Drive without installing an application. Is my understanding correct? Also I couldn't understand the place of destination Spreadsheet. 2. Are you required to use only python script? If my understanding of your situation is correct, it is required to use both python script and Google Apps Script as Web Apps.

Comment: I'll try to set it up as straight forward as possible
1: Users run a python script(compiled to exe) that grabs a file from our sales software......

Comment: 2: the file that the software spits out is unsorted unusable garbage, so the script then sorts it and arranges it......

Comment: 3: the user can specify where to save the file that the script creates, but we save it to a spot on the hard drive that syncs to the web so that ALL users can view and edit it online at the same time... most of which dont need to add anything extra to it, but some add Notes, such as shipping info or expected arrival of new product......

Comment: 4: several times a day we update the file by running the script again to grab a fresh report with fresh info....

Comment: 5: currently, somebody has to manually look at the new file and the older file with the online notes, and manually copy them into the new file(very time consuming) before saving the new file into the same online location........

Comment: 6: so we have 2 files created by the script, an older version with some User entered notes on it, and a fresh new version that needs those user notes copied into it.

Comment: 7: the Destination of the original File, is on the users hard drive on a shared google drive folder that everybody has access to online.
the destination of teh new file, will be to overwrite the existing file...but a temporary file can be created on the hard drive in any location if it needs to make a temp file before saving over top of the old file.

Comment: Thank you for your quick and polite response. I think that from your reply comment, I recommend to update your question. It will help users think of the solution or workaround. By the way, I have several questions. 1. Can I ask you about the part that you have already achieved and the part that you have not been able to achieve? 2. Is the file of ``grabs a file from our sales software`` XLSX file? 3. Is the Google drive of ``a shared google drive folder that everybody has access to online.`` yours?

Comment: the file location is not important to this part `all that matters is I need help getting comments and notes from file #1 into File#2` I need it to compare and look for the same items in the new file and to place the comments in the new file at the correct location `I will add an example to the original post of what I am trying to do`

Comment: Thank you for replying and updating your question. Unfortunately, I cannot still see the clear vision of your goal. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this. When you give me a time to understand about what you want to do, I'm glad.